# OpenGL shader not drawing anything - bad sprite class

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I'm trying to encapsulate OpenGL rendering in a renderer class.

I'm pretty sure my window class works fine (I've checked for errors) but I think the error is in my sprite class but I have no idea what it is.

This is my sprite class:

sprite_renderer.hpp

```cpp
#ifndef SPRITE_RENDERER_H
#define SPRITE_RENDERER_H

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include "shader.hpp"


class SpriteRenderer
{
public:
    SpriteRenderer(Shader &shader);
    ~SpriteRenderer();
    void DrawSprite();
private:
    Shader shader; 
    GLuint quadVAO;
    void initRenderData();
};

#endif
```

sprite_renderer.cpp

```
#include "sprite_renderer.hpp"

SpriteRenderer::SpriteRenderer(Shader &shader)
{
    this->shader = shader;
    this->initRenderData();
}

SpriteRenderer::~SpriteRenderer()
{
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &this->quadVAO);
}

void SpriteRenderer::DrawSprite()
{
    this->shader.Use();

    glBindVertexArray(this->quadVAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void SpriteRenderer::initRenderData()
{
    GLuint VBO;
    GLfloat vertices[] = { 
        // Pos      
        0.0f, 1.0f, 
        1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 

        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 
        1.0f, 0.0f, 
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &this->quadVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(this->quadVAO);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

I'm using it like this in my main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    Window window = Window();
    Shader shader = ResourceManager::LoadShader("./assets/shaders/sprite.vert", "./assets/shaders/sprite.frag", "sprite");
    SpriteRenderer* renderer = new SpriteRenderer(shader);

    while (window.IsOpen())
    {
        window.BeginDraw();
        renderer->DrawSprite();
        window.EndDraw();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Where `window.BeginDraw()` and `window.EndDraw()` are just:

```
void Window::BeginDraw()
{
  glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void Window::EndDraw()
{
  glfwSwapBuffers(window);
  glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Comment: `glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0)` has to be  `glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0)`. the size of the attribute tuple is 2, because each vertex coordinate consists of 2 components (x, y) - even if the type in the vertex shader is `vec4`. The missing components are automatically set by 0 (for y and z) respectively 1 (for w).

Comment: Ah okay, I'd simplified this example to take out what I thought was irrelevant. I've replaced that line in my code and I still don't get anything rendered

Comment: Edited the post to reflect your comment

Answer (score 1):

Just to rule out the obvious, try sticking a print statement in the destructor of your Shader class. Judging by the design of your Shader class, you should find it extremely easy to end up calling glDeleteProgram prior to actually using the shader.

In general, if you have a wrapper around a GLSL shader or program, you probably want to delete the copy constructor and assignment operator (or implement a ref counting system).

\edit to delete the copy ctor & assignment operator....

```cpp
Shader(const Shader&) = delete;
Shader& operator = (const Shader&) = delete;
```

You probably want to manage these shaders somewhere *(possibly ref counted)*, and only store pointers to them within your SpriteRenderer. 
I can't see any other problem with the code you've posted above, so the issue may be within your shader, or how you are passing any uniform variables you're using.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly whats happening: the shaders destructor is being called before rendering. I'm not clear how I should 'delete the copy constructor', do I just make them empty functions?

Comment: This didn't actually help, but maybe it points to more things I'm doing wrong!